# Pandas df sum groupby column for all dates

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following `df qty` which has date with repetitive items with qty.

```
DF qty
|    date    | qty  |   item   | ccy |
+------------+------+----------+-----+
| 2015-01-01 |  700 | CB04 box | USD |
| 2015-01-01 |  500 | CB04 box | USD |
| 2015-01-01 | 1500 | AB01 box | USD |
| 2015-01-02 |  550 | CB04 box | USD |
| 2015-01-02 |  750 | AB01 box | USD |
| 2015-01-02 |  500 | AB01 box | USD |
| 2015-01-03 |  100 | AB01 box | USD |
| 2015-01-03 |  200 | AB01 box | USD |
| 2015-01-03 |  300 | AB01 box | USD |
```

I need some suggestion on, how can I make this `DF qty` be like the following:

```
DF qty
|    date    | qty  |   item   | ccy |
+------------+------+----------+-----+
| 2015-01-01 | 1200 | CB04 box | USD |
| 2015-01-01 | 1500 | AB01 box | USD |
| 2015-01-02 |  550 | CB04 box | USD |
| 2015-01-02 | 1250 | AB01 box | USD |
| 2015-01-03 |  600 | AB01 box | USD |
```

what I was doing was, making a subset `df` for each `date` and then group them by `qty`.

`qty = qty[qty[date] == '2015-01-01']`

**then**

```
## Sum items lots 
qty = qty.groupby('item').agg({'date': 'first',
                                'ccy':'first',    
                                'qty' : 'sum'}).reset_index()
```

This process is very repetitive, I want some thing that will do this for all `dates` and sum up the `item` for `qty`

Answer (score 1):

You can `groupby` multiple columns at the same time. In this case it looks like you want find the total sum for a given item on the same day in the same currency. This means you want to groupby `['date', 'item', 'ccy']`

```
df.groupby(['date', 'item', 'ccy']).sum().reset_index()
```

Outputs:

```
         date      item  ccy   qty
0  2015-01-01  AB01_box  USD  1500
1  2015-01-01  CB04_box  USD  1200
2  2015-01-02  AB01_box  USD  1250
3  2015-01-02  CB04_box  USD   550
4  2015-01-03  AB01_box  USD   600
```